# Automate the XCode build settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, applescript, xcodebuild

I've developed a static library that I'd like to share between XCode projects. I did some reading to learn exactly how to include this library as a binary dependency so that it runs on both the device and the simulator and that lead to a couple of manual steps which I'd now like to automate. Overall I'd like to be able to release new versions of my library and have a simple upgrade process for any project using the older version. Currently that process consists of deleting and/or copying the new binary files over the original location, deleting copying over new header files. The initial install consists of the same two steps along with additional project/target level configuration to set conditional linker flags based on the target SDK. Is there a way this could be automated? I mean I know I could do something like write an Applescript to do the heavy lifting but how? Has anyone ever automated xcode build settings via applescript? How would I call into XCode via Applescript? Are there any other alternatives? Is there a better way to maintain binary level dependencies?

**Update**

I'm looking to maintain a *binary level* dependency where project A depends on a static library created by project B. Something similar to a framework that can be included into an XCode iPhone project easily. After building "B" I want something that can practically be dropped into and project including A. While I am becoming aware of all the procedures around leveraging such a dependency I am looking for some solutions to soften up all of the rough edges.

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom build script through `Xcode`:

- select your target under the Targets group on the left
- select Add -> New Build Phase -> New Run Script Build Phase
- double click on the new Run Script item underneath your target
- this allows you to write a shell script, accessing most of the Xcode environment variables related to the current build, e.g. `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`
- if you check the "**Show environment variables in build log**" and view the detailed build output you can see all the variables available.

Have a Google search and you'll find lots of examples, e.g. [section 20.3 here](http://six.manoverboard.org/book.html) etc.

If you are using Subversion I believe you can use [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) to specify which particular version of your library to use.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to drag & drop your library project in your project. xCode will dot the rest...

Regards,

Thierry

Comment: I'm not looking to use source dependency, rather I'm trying to figure out best practice for library binary dependencies. With an A->B dependency, I want the B output to be a a product that can be easily included into any XCode project sans source code.